# Monte Carlo simulation and distributions

Tags: monte-carlo

I just started my learning process about the Monte Carlo Simulation.

Does this method always require specifying a distribution type for the random inputs? I would like to attempt a simple modelling of natural phenomena using inputs defined within constrained intervals, but I don't know how those are distributed.

Comment: Is not necessary to know the distribution, you can use the empirical distribution function.

Comment: Almost by definition, it's impossible to even start a Monte Carlo simulation without providing information equivalent to the full joint distribution of all inputs.  (An empirical distribution function is still a distribution, btw.)  Could you therefore clarify what you mean by "require specifying"?